# Doctrine many-to-many association is not resolved

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

When i am using a Many-To-Many relationship in Symfony2 using Doctrine ORM i get the problem that my many-to-many relationship is not resolved.

Example:

```
    Class A:

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="StoreItem", mappedBy="itemOptions")
     */
    protected $storeItems;

    Class B:
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="StoreItemOption", inversedBy="storeItems")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="store_item_itemoptions")
     */
    protected $itemOptions;
```

now i store the object in a session, note that i did not called the many to many relationship yet by using

```
    ->getItemOptions()
```

When i get my session object now and do **->getItemOptions()** then it is empty.

Anybody has an idea what is causing this?

*(PS: I found a hacky solution by saying that when i add an item to my cart i do a empty foreach that calls the method ->getItemOptions())*

Answer (score 1):

This is called 'lazy loading', and is a doctrine feature designed to reduce memory overhead.

You can set loading to 'eager' or explicitly add a select for the other field in your DQL to avoid lazy loading: e.g.:

```
$objectsA=$em->createQueryBuilder('\Class\A', 'a')
             ->join('a.b', 'b')
             ->addSelect('b')
             ->getQuery()
             ->getResult();
```

Comment: OK thank you, i thougth that it had something to do with lazy loading but didn't knew how to solve this, thank you very much!